# Where to implement business calculations on a query using Clean architecture

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cqrs, clean-architecture

We are re-building our core application trying to use clean architecture and CQRS.
Projects have all been set up.

Currently this is all working

[image]

Domain layer currently holds complex models ie. models that simply map to the results from a stored proc.

```
namespace UHNM.myHotelCore.Domain.Entities.floor
{
public class FloorCx
{
    public int      FloorId      { get; set; }
    public int      x            { get; set; }
    public int      y            { get; set; }
    public string   FloorCode    { get; set; }
    public string   Floor        { get; set; }
}
```

}

This is all working.  We now want to introduce calculations.

We use generally use automapper in our query handler in the application layer to map our complexmodel to our returned DTO.

```
var floors = _autoMapper.Map<List<FloorDTO>>(_floor.GetFloors(request.FloorId));
```

Our return model from the API looks like this :-

```
namespace UHNM.myHotelCore.Application.CQRS.Queries.Floor.DTO
{
public class Floor
{
    public int      FloorId      { get; set; }
    public decimal  Average      { get; set; }
    public string   FloorCode    { get; set; }
    public string   Floor        { get; set; }
}
```

}

Where average is calculated based on x and y from the complex model.
Using clean architecture, where is generally the best place for these calculations to go? and at what point are they called?

Would they sit within FloorCx?

```
 public class FloorCx
{
    public int      FloorId      { get; set; }
    public int      x            { get; set; }
    public int      y            { get; set; }
    public string   FloorCode    { get; set; }
    public string   Floor        { get; set; }


Public decimalCalculateAverage(int x, int y)
{
//Calculation goes here 
}
  }
```

Create a separate class for the calculations?
Or even a separate project for business logic?

Comment: In OOP, the idea was that the data and methods operating on that data should be stored together in a class. Hence I would put in into the FloorCx class.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your `FloorCx` is placed in Domain layer. The current shape of that class is a pure anemic model, which is an [anti pattern in DDD world](https://thedomaindrivendesign.io/anemic-model/).

Not sure if your intention is to follow DDD principles as well, but if it is, then you could introduce repositories that return your `FloorCx` **data models**, which then you map to your real **business objects**. Such business objects should have business behavior, so having calculations inside is a way to go as long as the calculations can be self-contained, meaning they rely on object's internal properties, or accept primitive types (to reduce coupling between your domain model and other resources). When the calculations require more information from the outside world, you can create business services that do them.

Also, in DDD world, AutoMapper and similar solutions [are often discouraged](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/), also because your domain objects should not have public setters on their properties, but rather expose constructors or static factory methods that control what is initialized and how, ensuring object's internal consistency.

Having that said, I would create `FloorCxDataModel` that represents objects fetched from your repository (which abstracts away the stored procedure call and transformations), which then is mapped to a `FloorCx` business model that exposes methods for calculations and other business behavior. If those calculations depend on external information, for simple types that should work too, but for more complex input parameters I would create a `FloorCxCalculationService` that resides in Domain layer and does necessary calculations for you.

In the end, you map that business object to your `FloorDto` (which contains only data, no additional behavior) and return it from your API. In my view, that DTO should also have read-only public properties and have constructor/static factory method that does initialization.